# 500 server error with hiding .htm and .html file extensions on non-existing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need to improve this rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.htm [L]
```

Per my hosting company: The reason for 500 errors on non-existent pages is because of the the above rewrite rules used by your application, which are as follows:
the rules above mean that any request to a non-existent file or directory will be  redirected to URI.htm where URI is the requested URI.

Continuing: In this example `archives.hwg.org/thispagedoesnotexist` is being rewritten to `archives.hwg.org/thispagedoesnotexist.htm` , which is a nonexistent page so the rewrite rules try to once again rewrite the request to `archives.hwg.org/thispagedoesnotexist.htm.htm` , which is also nonexistent. This continues to loop until the following error is generated.

Here are some of my actual site files using the above rewrite rule, but if you try to type in a non-existing file or directory you will see the `500 error`.

This is link format to actual file:
   `archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory/01082413075904.02137@kira.pacbell.net`
This is the actual file:
   `archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory/01082413075904.02137@kira.pacbell.net.htm`

This is link format to actual file:
`archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory/2001/07`
This is the actual file:
`archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory/2001/07.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `archives.hwg.org` is the domain, then this should work. The rules have to be performed in order. In a different order the files will not be found initially and the server will loop multiple times until a match is found (making the interaction with the server slower for every page.)

We're checking if the file is a non-existent. If it's non-existent, then we try to go one "directory" down. Ultimately we get to any file and any directory that doesn't exist ends up going back to the homepage `index.html`.

**Note** if anything on the site changes or you're experiencing an error in a particular directory, the server is trying to redirect the user to a file ending specifically in `.htm`. According to the rules all files in folders have to end with `.htm`.

Remember that everything in Unix/Linux is case sensitive (unless purposely overridden). Additionally web servers look for the specific files they're queried for. Your specific main file is `index.html`, not `index.htm`.

The `500` error typically happens because a loop is created when you're looking for a file that is non-existent but being redirected back to that same file.

If you're responsible for maintaining the server you need to check out [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in the event you accidentally create this sort of issue again.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/$2.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /$1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: I used the first 3 rewrite rules and works (as old rule), but still getting errors if you type any non-existing files. and yes you can test yourself the errors as archives.hwg.org is the domain name. The 2 set of rules worked as well without the R-301 as the .htm and html files do exist.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code to make it not match anything that was an intended filename with a period.

Comment: I get errors for all the pages archives.hwg.org when using the newly edited version. I reverted back to your previous working version, but still errors for non-existing files.   I realized I do not need to hide the .html extension but just need to ignore index.html files on the subdirectory, e.g archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory and the year e.g. archives.hwg.org/hwg-theory/2003 folders. so not sure if you are adding rule code that would conflict for .html files which may be causing the new errors.

Comment: the first three of four work rules together work, but when include the fourth rule. i get server errors.  When using this lastest version. HOWEVER. I don't get '500 server error' for missing files, but now it doesn't ignore file case characters so some of the pages don't display.

Comment: the 3rd section of the rewrite is still causing 500 server errors as  the rule mean that any request to a non-existent file or directory will be redirected to URI.htm where URI is the requested. Can you modify so non-existing pages do not create / redirect to .htm ?

Comment: I"m using this and seems to fix the 500 server error, but only on non-existing files after the first sub-directory, not the sub-subdirectories.  


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.htm